# Как узнать значения каждого индекса массива?

Tags: delphi, массивы

Есть массив состоящий из трехмерных массивов , я хочу узнать, что находится в каждом индексе mkts, как это лучше и проще узнать все значения в каждом индексе? Как обращаться по индексу , чтобы узнать значение ?

```
mkts = array [0..3, 1..6, 1..16] of SmallInt;
TPmkts = ^mkts;
Pkts: array[1..Blocks, 1..RTParts] of TPmkts = ( (nil, nil),
                            (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil) );
```

Comment: можно использовать вложенные  цикл в цикле в цикле...
или написать функцию рекурсивного перебора элементов

Comment: @ВиталийВихляев я был бы рад, если бы вы написали пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var
  a, b, c, d, e: Integer;
  item: TPmkts;
begin
  for a := Low(Pkts) to High(Pkts) do
    for b := Low(Pkts[a]) to High(Pkts[a]) do begin
      item := Pkts[a, b];
      if item <> nil then begin
        for c := Low(item^) to High(item^) do
          for d := Low(item^[c]) to High(item^[c]) do
            for e := Low(item^[c, d]) to High(item^[c, d]) do
              ShowMessage(IntToStr(item^[c, d, e]));
      end;
   end;
end;
```